# Adding new scopes to Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I am developing a Chrome extension which uses oauth2. This is the current scope definition:

```
"scopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
]
```

When adding a new scope like so:

```
"scopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
  , "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me"
]
```

I receive 
    "OAuth2 request failed: Service responded with error: 'Bad Request'"

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?
Do I need to manually invalidate the access token somehow?

Oddly this was working for a while but it stopped after I manually revoked permissions via https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1

Any insights as to what might be happening would be hugely appreciated. Massively spinning my wheels.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5):

Fixed for now! In this instance, changing the scope to use auth/plus.login instead seemed to work. i.e:

```
"scopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
]
```

I don't really know why one works and the other doesn't. Best answer still up for grabs.

Comment: Phenomenally, it does work! Official tutorial has an empty array of scopes, causing an error. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much. This fixed the problem for me. Good thing it's well documented and all .. 2-hours down the drain.

Comment: More than 4 hours went down the drain for a lack of documentation. That sucks.